# How can I concatenate all JS files in a folder?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat

I have a main app folder with many subfolders, each with their own subfolders, etc, which along the way contain `.js` files.

I want to create a grunt task that concatenates all the `.js` files anywhere under this main top level folder, which is called `src`.

Is there anyway to do that?

Right now, I have

```
            cwd: '.',
            src: [
                'src/**/**/*.js',
                'src/**/**/**/*.js',
                'src/**/**/**/**/*.js',
            ],
            dest: 'dist/app/superapp.js'
```

but this doesn't account for all possible `.js` file locations. And if I add a new `.js` in some folder, I don't want to have to manually update the grunt task.

Comment: Are all the files under `app` or `src`? If `src` you should only need the single `src/**/*.js` line to do the trick.

Comment: maybe you're overdoing the wildcards, `**/*.js` should match any depth.

Comment: @Andy good catch. I meant to say they're all under `src`. I edited

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [grunt docs](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns), `src/**/*.js` is all you need here.

> foo/**/*.js will match all files ending with .js in the foo/ subdirectory and all of its subdirectories.